# Find a prime number p that is simultaneously expressible in the forms $x^2 + y^2, u^2 + 2v^2$, and $r^2 + 3s^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**background**: From Burton, Number Theory 9.3#8 with a hint: (−1/p) = (−2/p) = (−3/p) = 1.]

Based on the previous problem 6:
$n^2+1, n^2+2$, or $n^2+3$ have solutions when  $n^2\equiv-i\mod p$ $(\frac{-i}{p})=1$ This occurs when p = 2 or p ≡ 1 (mod 4); p = 2 or p ≡ 1 or 3 (mod 8);
p = 2, p = 3 or p ≡ 1 (mod 6) respectively.

Now to the original question, the hint is satisfied when $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{p\equiv 1 \mod 12}\quad p\equiv 1 \mod 24$ but I don't see how to use this to find the prime satisfying the equations $x^2 + y^2, u^2 + 2v^2$, and $r^2 + 3s^2$.

Comment: $$ 73  $$  note that $1 \pmod {12}$ is not enough, $13$ does not work

Comment: @Will Yes, it's in the back of the book, but I need more of a hint than that. I don't understand what calculation produced that.

Comment: $37$ does not work either. Or $61$

Comment: Are you using trial and error on primes of the form 1+12i to see if you can find number that fit the three forms or is there a way to explicitly solve the three equations to find p?

Comment: I was hoping you would notice the hint that $13 \pmod{24}$ does not work

Comment: Yeah, lcm$(4,8,3)=24$.

Comment: @user135711 Since $p \equiv 13 \pmod{24}$ doesn't work (it contradicts the congruence conditions modulo $8$), try $p \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$. The smallest such prime is $p = 73$.

Comment: @Lubin, ahh, Ok I see. The mod does have to be 24 by extended CRT, LCM is 24. Good point.

Comment: Much more interesting to reformulate the problem and write the parameterization of the solutions of this system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Using Legendre symbol rules, one can deduce that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
p &\equiv 1 \pmod 4, \\
p &\equiv 1,7 \pmod 8, \\
p &\equiv 1,11 \pmod{12}. \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
The above system has no solution unless $p$ is equivalent to $1$ modulo $4,8,12$. In this case, $$p \equiv 1 \pmod{24}.$$
The smallest such prime is $p = 73$, and indeed we find that
$$73 = 3^2 + 8^2 = 1^2 + 2\cdot6^2 = 5^2 + 3\cdot 4^2.$$

Comment: Two questions: 1)How does finding a prime that satisfies $n^2+i$ translate to a prime that satisfies $n^2+in_2^2$, 2) Where are you getting $7\mod8$ and $11\mod 12$ from? $(\frac{-1}{p}\frac{2}{p}$ is satisfied by $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $p\equiv 3 \mod 8$ which is (-1)(-1) based on legendre notation. and $(\frac{-1}{p}\frac{3}{p}$ is satisfied by $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $p\equiv 7 \mod 12$ Which is $p\equiv 1,7 \mod 12$ or $1\mod 6$

Comment: Ethan, the second should be $1,3 \pmod 8.$ The third should be $1 \pmod 3.$ Your conditions would make sense for $x^2 - 2 y^2$ and $x^2 - 3 y^2.$

Comment: The second one needs detail. For prime $p > 3$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12},$ $x^2 - 3 y^2$ represents $p$ itself. For prime $q > 3$ and $q \equiv 11 \pmod {12},$ $x^2 - 3 y^2$ represents $-q$